# How can I quickly find the files I just pasted into a folder?

Tags: macos, finder, copy-paste

I have some issues when I copy and paste files on my Mac (with Ventura 13.4.1).

So, when I copy and paste a file/s from one folder to another folder, the last inserted/copied file/s is/are NOT selected in the destination folder. When I want to rename it/them, or use it/them for some reason I have to look for it/them, select it/them and press Enter. And if the file/s have been modified a week ago that makes my process very slow. I am a DJ and I use this when I copy and paste songs and I want quickly to add them into my playlist, but I can't...

Is there a setting (or a shortcut) to select (or highlight) the last insterted/copied file(s)?

Comment: I often tag the existing files with a color then anything new is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by Date Added, then they'll always be at the top.
In List view, right click the header bar & add Date added, then click that header to sort by. You can drag the columns into whichever order you prefer.

[image]

Just to note that if you drag & drop to *the same volume* they stay selected.